# Recover ifstream from failed read

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

I currently have a piece of code that reads in text from a file using an ifstream. Each line of this file corresponds to a different piece of data that must be encoded into a struct. My "encodeLine" function takes care of this.

For safety, I want my system to be able to handle data that is too big to fit into its variable. For example, if the number 999999999 is read into a short, I want the program to be able to continue on reading the rest of the lines.

Currently, when I encounter data like this, I print out "ERROR" and clear the stream. However, when I perform more reads, the data that is read is corrupted. For example, on the next line the number "1" should be read, but instead something like 27021 is read.

How can the ifstream be reset to continue with valid reads?

Here is my code:

```cpp
ifstream inputStream;
inputStream.open(foo.txt);
char token[64];

int totalSize = 0;

// Priming read
inputStream >> token;

while(inputStream.good())
{
    // Read and encode line of data from file
    totalSize = totalSize + encodeLine(inputStream, &recordPtr, header, filetypeChar)

    if(!inputStream.eof() && !inputStream.good())
    {
         printf("ERROR");
         inputStream.clear();
    }
    else if(inputStream.eof())
    {
         break;
    }

    inputStream >> token;
}
```

Comment: The bad data is left in the stream and usually needs to be `ignore`d. A better trick, when it makes sense, is to read an entire record from the file without parsing it. Feed this record into a `std::istringstream` and parse the istringstream. If the `istringstream` blows up, the file is still intact and pointing at the next record.

Comment: Sidenote: eof is only set if the program reads past the end of the file. Depending on how you've written `encodeLine`, you may be setting yourself up  for troubles. If you read part of a record and hit the end of the file, leaving you with an incomplete record that you won't notice until later. Another common failure happens when the file ends exactly on the end of a record.The program will read the last record, not find the eof, loop around and fail instantly when it tries to read the next record.